# Galois group of $E/K$ & Galois group of the extension $E$ over Fixed field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I've proved this result for myself, but I have doubt in my proof whether it is true :

> Let $E/K$ be a field extension and $G(E/K)$ its Galois group. Suppose $E^{G(E/K)}$ is its Fixed field, i.e. $\{x\in E\,|\:\forall\,\sigma\in G(E/K):\sigma(x)=x\}$.
>   Is it true that:
>   $$G(E/K)=G(E/E^{G(E/K)}) \:?$$

Let $K'=E^{G(E/K)}$. Here is my proof :

First, It is obvious that $K\subseteq K'$ and then $G(E/K')\subseteq G(E/K) \tag{*}$

Now, suppose $\phi\in G(E/K)$ and it's sufficient to prove $\phi\in G(E/K')$ or equivalently $\phi$ fixes all members of $K'$. And this is also clear as for all $y\in K'$, we have $\sigma(x)=x$, for every $\sigma\in G(E/K)$, especially for $\phi$.

This result, if it's correct, states a nice property that for any arbitrary extension of *finite* degree $E/K$, there exists an **intermediate** subfield, like $K'$, that :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(i)&K\subseteq K'\subseteq E\\
(ii)&\text{$E/K'$ is a Galois extension (See [Proposition 6.1.3][1])}\\
(iii)& \:\:G(E/K)=G(E/K')
\end{array}\right.$$

Or for any *Galois group*, there's a *Galois Extension* belongs to it !

---

# **EDIT**

The main problem I was working with was the following problem :

> Let $E/K$ a field extension of finite degree. Prove that every subgroup $G$ of $G(E/K)$ is finite and $|G|$ divides $[E:K]$.

Comment: $G(E/K)$ isn't defined if $E/K$ isn't Galois, so this problem isn't even well-posed. Do you mean the automorphism group of $E/K$?

Comment: You can just regard $G(E/K)$ as the group of $K$-Automorphisms of $E$. There's no problem. Galois group can be defined for any extension :)

Comment: However, it's not actually called a Galois group unless $E/K$ is Galois.

Comment: Also, the Proposition which I'm assuming your citing only works if (and here I'm going to use more standard notation) $\operatorname{Aut}(E/K)$ is finite. But that's good enough for the problem at hand.

Comment: thank you @AviSteiner. In my main problem that I was working before $Aut(E/K)$ was finite. But is *finiteness* neccessory for the proof ?

Comment: I think it is. However, I don't know enough about infinite degree field extensions to give you a conclusive answer. If you're interested in the topic, I'd suggested looking up things like profinite groups and the Krull topology. As for specific references...